# eclipse indigo constantly freezing and giving problems

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Ive been getting alot of weird problems with my eclipse Ide the last day or so and I would like to reinstall some or all components of it to try to correct the issue, I noticed last night that my background services in my android project stopped working when I would launch the project I was working on, yet It would then launch when I would open up another project so I began doing that instead as a work around, I then began getting issues where when I relaunched the emulator it would freeze at 27% every other time and I would have to restart the ide over and over again.

what I would like to do is reinstall the jdk, and if that doesnt work I would like to reinstall eclipse, however the dilemma Im having is Im not sure If I will lose all my work If I do this, what is the best thing to do?

Comment: things are misreable after ADT 16.0, It's not running smooth as before...

Comment: try vim. it won'tlet you down. i am also fed up with the low efficiency and never end waiting, then i changed to vim. until now, i am feeling good. BTW, i am a android programmer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse can get really frustrating and hard to fix but it is also very easy to install. You donT actually *uninstall* or *install* anything, Eclipse can be run without changing the registry.

I ll suggest, before you lose any more hair or your sanity:

- archive your existing indigo and workspace
- get a new copy of Eclipse (indigo again, why not)
- re install Android environment
- import your projects, clean, fix ..etc.

Apparently this is a rather common problem, not your particular %27 problem but the general Eclipse *fix* vs *reinstall* dilemma. IMHO, a clean start saves from a lot of trouble.

Comment: the workspace is basically a folder. When you _install_ a new eclipse, either set the new workspace to path of this folder _or_ use `File -> Import` to select the projects to import to your new workspace.